# Struts 2: Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException with tiles in session variable null

Tags: hibernate, nullpointerexception, struts2, tiles

My question is why I get a NullPointerException, especially in my variable session, the console log is:

```
Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.curso.struts2.dao.UserDAOImpl.listUser(UserDAOImpl.java:28)
at com.curso.struts2.UserAction.list(UserAction.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 ...
```

My source code is:

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts> 
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default,struts-default" namespace="/">

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="addUser" method="add" class="com.curso.struts2.UserAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
    </action>

    <action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.curso.struts2.UserAction">
        <result name="success">register.tiles</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<User> listUser() {  
    List<User> courses = null;
    try { 
        System.out.println("UserDAOImpl.listUser()_session:" + session);
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
        courses = query.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return courses;
}
```

In this case **session** variable prints null

**tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="/register.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Struts 2 Hibernate example"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/register.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

In my register.jsp i send a form

Comment: You are getting error because you havn't initialize session in anywhere